# Wait for level up or evolve my Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-go

Found out that having higher level allows you to naturally find and catch higher level Pokemon. If I have level 23 Pidgey (for example) and enough candy to evolve. Should I evolve the Pokemon, or wait for a higher level Pokemon so that I get a better Pidgeotto?

Is there a balance to be struck between evolving vs holding out for better level?

Comment: Waiting is always the better option, but this has been asked here multiple times already.

Answer (score 0):

It have been said by many: **Evolving first is better**. So far I was not able to find anyone to say something against it.